# jQuery click OUT with overlay

Tags: jquery

I would like it that when the user clicks out of the #email-form div, it is hidden and #stamp is displayed again. I am trying to do this with an overlay div, but it's not working..

```
            jQuery('#email-form').hide();

        jQuery('#stamp').click(function()  {
            jQuery(this).hide();    
            jQuery('#email-form').show();
            jQuery(

        });

        jQuery('.overlay').click(function() {
                jQuery('#email-form').hide();
                jQuery('#stamp').show();
        });
```

---------------------------------- HTML ------------------------------

```
 <div class="overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
 <div id="stamp"><img src="email_postmark.png"/></div>
 <div id="email-form">
    <form id="signup" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
         <span id="response">
     <?php require ('store-address.php'); if($_GET['submit']){ echo storeAddress(); } ?>
     </span>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="TYPE EMAIL & PRESS ENTER"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Here is an alternative idea: Bind an event handler to `document.onclick` - then stop the propagation of all clicks that bubble through to #email-form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/awEGq/1/

The `position:fixed` makes sure that it always fills up the entire background, even if you have scrollbars. If you use `position:absolute`, you can scroll past the overlay.

Because of the `display:fixed`, the overlay is placed on top of the rest of the page. To prevent this, I placed it further back with the `z-index`.

The `background-color` is just for show, to show where the overlay is. You can remove it in your live implementation.

Comment: For some reason when I click on the overlay to bring back the image, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in my comment, here is a different approach:

```
var hideEmailForm = function() {
    jQuery('#email-form').hide();
    jQuery('#stamp').show();
};

jQuery('#stamp').click(function(event)  {
    jQuery(this).hide();    
    jQuery('#email-form').show();

    event.stopPropagation();  // <-- NEW!
    jQuery(document).one('click', hideEmailForm);
});

jQuery('#email-form').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Remember to unbind "hideEmailForm" from document.onclick whenever you're hiding #email-form!

```
jQuery('#email-form').unbind('click', hideEmailForm);
```

Comment: This loads the page with both elements showing and then when I click #stamp it just hides #email-form.

Comment: This is just a snippet, you need to integrate this with your existing code.

Comment: You're right - the propagation of the click on #stamp needs to be stopped as well, otherwise this click bubbles up to the document root and triggers the hideEmailForm event handler right away. I've updated the code and made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MNYH9/

Comment: That helped with the image being replaced by the form, but it's still not reverting back to the image when I click elsewhere.

Comment: Did you try the fiddle, it works for me - clicking on the red area makes the green one appear (the form), clicking somewhere in the white area around it makes the red one reappear.